# Is it ok if my 15-month-old son stops breastfeeding by himself?

Tags: toddler, health, breastfeeding, baby-led-weaning

My 1 year and 3 months old baby suddenly has stopped breastfeeding at night. I have tried to feed him several times but he is not interested. He is eating solid food but not interested in the breast anymore and whenever I try he moves away. My mother says I should start cowmilk now. I have checked him and there is no stomach pain. I also consulted a doctor for this and he said that my child is normal.

Is it ok if baby decides to stop breastfeeding?

Comment: If your doctor says this is normal, then it more than likely is.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, your doctor is the authoritative voice here. The doctor says your toddler is okay, so I would listen to them before asking strangers on the internet.

If you do want some reassurance though, yes, children all have different times they stop breast feeding. Some wean themselves early, others would keep going forever. Your baby is already happy with solids and is less interested in you so go with that. This sort of age is fine to stop breast feeding.

Follow-on milks are more tailored to humans than cow milk, but either will be fine to supplement solid food.